# How to create a overlay with help bubbles on Android?

Tags: android, overlay, android-relativelayout

I recall seeing some android apps having a help overlay that greys the screen a bit and provides textbubbles with helpfull information pointing to various UI objects.

I thought this to be easy, just create a `FrameLayout`with 2 layers, 1 content, 1 helpoverlay.
However, it appears that you can't use a `RelativeLayout` with items that are based upon another `RelativeLayout`?

How would I go to position these bubbles? Manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216937/how-do-i-create-a-help-overlay-like-you-see-in-a-few-android-apps-and-ics

Answer (score 4):

Use a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). a sample implementation can be found here : http://sree.cc/google/android/android-popup-window

You can use the popupWindow.showAsDropdown(View anchor) method to attach the popup to any view or manually set the x and y co-ordinates of the popup to be shown.

[EDIT]:
you may also want to have a look here : http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/