# What is the best way to implement "coach marks" in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface

What is the best way to implement "coach marks" in Android?

There is good example:

[image: There is good example]

Comment: Try these links: http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/android-layout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216937/how-do-i-create-a-help-overlay-like-you-see-in-a-few-android-apps-and-ics and [sample project](https://github.com/pranayairan/AndroidExamples/tree/master/AndroidHelpOverlay)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216937/how-do-i-create-a-help-overlay-like-you-see-in-a-few-android-apps-and-ics

Comment: You can put your activity content in a FrameLayout and add an additional view with such marks. If you don't want to get implement int yourself, check out this project https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView

Comment: The one part of the above diagram that will be more difficult than the one in the linked-to question from your answer is the "Tap to Reload" hint. That points to a specific action bar item (or what would be an action bar item if the screenshot were actually of an Android app... :-). Finding the on-screen coordinates of that item may be trouble. With respect to the sample project, that will only work for *very* simple "coach marks", as it uses a simple PNG file. That PNG file may not work well in landscape, for example.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216937/how-do-i-create-a-help-overlay-like-you-see-in-a-few-android-apps-and-ics/17091481#17091481

Comment: I'd rather go this way: if you think you have to add "coach marks" then your UI is too complicated.

Comment: i need to know the answer