# Creating Android overlays for displaying Walk-through

Tags: android, xml, layout, user-interface, overlay

This is what I've done to implement CommonsWare's answer in the following question:
[How do I create a help overlay like you see in a few Android apps and ICS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216937/how-do-i-create-a-help-overlay-like-you-see-in-a-few-android-apps-and-ics)

But it fails. There are no errors but nothing appears when I run (I've made sure that the ***isFirstTime()*** function below is functioning properly

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

if(isFirstTime())
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    final FrameLayout overlayFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    setContentView(overlayFrameLayout);

    overlayFrameLayout.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null));
    overlayFrameLayout.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null));

    overlayFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    overlayFrameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            overlayFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            overlayFrameLayout.removeViewAt(1);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

setContentView(R.layout.main);
ctx = getApplicationContext();
```

I'm pretty sure that I've gone wrong when creating the FrameLayout. Appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't see anything because you call setContentView twice and the R.layout.main is being inflated and replacing your previously created and assigned overlayFrameLayout. The following code should sort it out.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(isFirstTime()){
        final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, frameLayout, true);
        final View overlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, frameLayout, false);
        overlayView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                frameLayout.removeView(overlayView);
                return false;
            }
        });
        frameLayout.addView(overlayView);
        setContentView(frameLayout);
    }
    else{
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```