# android tutorials screen

Tags: android

I was really confused about this topic, so I had to ask. Being new on Android, I was thinking of creating an *introductory sort of tutorial like page* for the app I am working on, like the one's you see on *various apps that is used for the first time* in which they point out various features of the app, what functionality does this button perform when pressed, what does the menu item do, in a sort of a **dynamic** way.

What are these actually ?? Are they `splash screens`? Or are they something really different?

Comment: Take a look at [this question][1] on the subject


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216937/how-do-i-create-a-help-overlay-like-you-see-in-a-few-android-apps-and-ics

Comment: @GabeSechan thank you ... that cleared my doubt a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just made a tutorial screen for my app. What I did in my case was to :

1) Create snapshots of all the activities and their functions.

2) Then I used photoshop to put different markers defining the different areas in the snapshot and what they do. (which look similar to the link posted in the above comments)

3) Then I used an Imageswitcher with a next button at its bottom. At the start of the app if the user wants to view the tutorial I just start an activity with the Imageswitcher.

4) I then cycle through all the snapshots with the help of the next button below the ImageSwitcher.

5) On the last image of the ImageSwitcher I just launch an Intent to open the main screen of the actual app.

Hope this helps!!!