# Display an image over the view

Tags: android, image, animation, uiimageview

I am making a small application and I have noticed that a lot of people don't really check the menu to see all the possible options my app has, and I think that they don't know how to access it. 
I have seen this on an application some time ago, and I tought I should make something like that. 
I would like to display like a transparent image over the app with small arrow pointing to all the buttons that I have on my app. The problem is I don't really know how to make this and I thought may by somebody here knows how.

Comment: Besides writing so much description its better to always put a screenshots with some code .

Comment: I knew there has to be something there but I didn't know how is it called or how to search for it.

Comment: Also, check this out:

[How do I create a help overlay like you see in a few Android apps and ICS?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216937/how-do-i-create-a-help-overlay-like-you-see-in-a-few-android-apps-and-ics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [Showcaseview](http://espiandev.github.io/ShowcaseView/) library.

> The ShowcaseView library is designed to highlight and showcase
>   specific parts of apps to the user with a distinctive and attractive
>   overlay. This library is great for pointing out points of interest for
>   users, gestures, or obscure but useful items.