# Overlay dialog - align view

Tags: android, layout, alignment, overlay

I want to implement a help overlay for my app. 
It should look like this: [How do I create a help overlay like you see in a few Android apps and ICS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216937/how-do-i-create-a-help-overlay-like-you-see-in-a-few-android-apps-and-ics)

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.coach_mark);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
//for dismissing anywhere you touch
View masterView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.coach_mark_master_view);
masterView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
dialog.show();
```

This works very well. The RelativeLayout of coach_mark.xml is displayed over my existing layout which was set via setContentView().
Now I want to align the views of coach_mark.xml near the according views of the existing layout, in order to react dynammically to the resolution and screen size. This is what I have tried:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.view_of_main_layout);
        view_of_the_overlay.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

But the view is displayed just in the middle of the screen.
The only thing I could archieve is to align the view to bottom of screen, but that is not what I want to do.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PopupWindow :

```
PopupWindow popup=new PopupWindow(this);
popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
popup.setWindowLayoutMode(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
popup.setContentView(R.layout.coach_mark);
View view=findById(R.id.view_of_main_layout);
int[] viewLocation=new int[2];
view.getLocationInWindow(viewLocation)
popup.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, viewLocation[0],viewLocation[1]);
```

you can also adjust to popup location with the last two variables which are the X and Y offest. Their values can also be negative.

Comment: Okay I have tried this, but now the view of the overlay is just shown in the left bottom corner.

Comment: showAtLocation has 4 parameters, use the first one as the anchor view, the second for gravity and that use the offset x and y for final location.

Comment: But I used the view_of_main_layout as anchor. So if I do not enter a special offset the popup should be displayed in the left-bottom corner of the anchor and not of the screen am I right?

Comment: I was mistaken, the view param is not an anchor, the layout is relative to the window. I have updated my answer.