# how to listen to draw over screen premission check when open the setting for it

Tags: android

in my app, it requires draw over app permission so I open setting using intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName());
        intent.setData(uri);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

so setting open and the user checks true to allow permission but he has to press back button to open my app again,
but when I try turecaller I detect when user check it's open app again without press to the back button.
how to make like this in my app

Comment: so you want to have permissions without going to settings?

Comment: no, i want to go to setting but when user allow this permission my application open again without user press to back button

Comment: [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: I don't think that there is a permission listener, but you can at least check every x miliseconds in a service for example.

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32652625/5110595) hope it will help you.

Comment: I wonder how truecaller detect that

Comment: @HemantParmar that already what I do I check first if the permission allow if no it launch setting activity but how to finish this activity after user check allow

Comment: @BhaveshDesai I try this but it doesn't launch setting activity or allow any thing

Comment: what is your target sdk version ?

Comment: minSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: @AhmedWahdan this only request permission, not opening setting screen, you have to show dialog for manually allow permission from setting if user deny permission.

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437721/how-to-give-screen-overlay-permission-on-my-activity)

Comment: I try this 
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE); //It will call onActivityResult Function After you press Yes/No and go Back after giving permission
but i user have to press back button also

Comment: you can see following link , i think work
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652533/android-system-overlay-window