# Overlay view without permission like Facebook messenger

Tags: android, overlay

When I develop app that requires overlay view I need to ask for "display over apps" permission almost every time. But Facebook messenger doesn't ask for anything, it just shows this view. Is there a way to do the same?

Comment: Once Try this This Helps.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40583163/2967727

Comment: @MLN, I already know how to ask for this permission if it is not accepted. However, Facebook messenger doesn't ask for anything and draws overlay view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having exactly the same question today. Turns out that Facebook Messenger also needs android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW window to show chat heads. You might have provided the permission in the past so it will not ask for permission on every installation. You can see 'draw over other apps' permission in Messenger app info, if you will disable it your messages will show in the notification instead of chat heads.[image: see this]
and [image: this]

Comment: I added SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW to manifest, but still I need to give explicit permission when open app.

Comment: Yes thats what I was saying facebook messenger also explicitly asks for permit drawing over other apps. This is asked on first time installation.