# Add a layer over your html page for assistance like Apple does?

Tags: tooltip, user-experience

When I log into icloud.com and go to Numbers, Pages, or Keynote, I'm shown a bunch of tips on how to get started and it points or highlights over different areas of the page. I can then toggle it off. How is that done and how can I implement something like that on my web site?

Answer (score 0):

These are called "coach marks", similar to chalk talk in sports. 
You can find a [pattern gallery](http://www.mobile-patterns.com/coach-marks) here. You will find this question and answer helpful: [How do I create a help overlay like you see in a few Android apps and ICS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216937/how-do-i-create-a-help-overlay-like-you-see-in-a-few-android-apps-and-ics)