# How make an Overlay who only detect gesture. Android 4.x

Tags: android, android-layout, overlay, gesture, gesture-recognition

I try to make a service who put an invisible overlay (transparent layout) on top of everything and detect the gesture for bind an event.
but when the overlay is on top, **everything under is inaccessible** (Applications).
*I have use this example : http://www.jawsware.mobi/code_OverlayView/*

How to create an overlay to catch gesture without trouble the others applications.

Comment: Check that post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216937/how-do-i-create-a-help-overlay-like-you-see-in-a-few-android-apps-and-ics hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you ordinarily would call `setContentView(R.layout.main)`, but on first run, you want to have this overlay.

Step #1: Create a `FrameLayout` in Java code and pass that to `setContentView().`

Step #2: Use `LayoutInflater` to inflate `R.layout.main` into the FrameLayout.

Step #3: Use `LayoutInflater` to inflate the overlay into the FrameLayout.

Step #4: When the user taps the button (or whatever) to dismiss the overlay, call `removeView()` to remove the overlay from the FrameLayout.

Since the overlay is a later child of the FrameLayout, it will float over top of the contents of `R.layout.main