# How to give tips for buttons in android?

Tags: android, hint

I am developing an application and in `homepage` it should show the hint about the button as `shown in image`. But i don't have idea. If any one knows help me. Below is the image what i am looking.  [image]

Comment: u can use [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

Comment: it may help you,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216937/how-do-i-create-a-help-overlay-like-you-see-in-a-few-android-apps-and-ics

Comment: Refer the below link,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031488/android-popupwindow-with-tooltip-arrow

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then you simply have to add title to the menu item .

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/skip_btn"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_skip_btn"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/skip_text"/>
```

Title mentioned will be shown when the user long presses the skip icon.